# Why doesn't the method authenticate take in an array with one object in it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Working with Rails 5.0.

I am learning with a tutorial how to do authentication, but was wondering why if you return a query with `Model.where(:somequery => some parameter)`, why doesn't the method `.authenticate` accept the result, which is an array with a single object/record? In the tutorial they put the word `.first`, to eliminate the array.

i.e.:

Portion of access_controller.rb (a controller within my app):

```
  def attempt_login
    if params[:username].present? && params[:password].present?
      found_user = AdminUser.where(:username => params[:username]).first
    #The above line .first removes the array given by .where

      if found_user
        authorized_user = found_user.authenticate(params[:password])
      end
    end


   if authorized_user
      session[:user_id] = authorized_user.id
      flash[:notice] = "You are now logged in."
      redirect_to(admin_path)
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = "Invalid username/password combination."
      render('login')
    end

  end
```

Why doesn't the `found_user` work with an array with a single object in it (without `.first`)? Isn't `array = [object] equal to  array = object`, if there's one object within the array?

Comment: Why use `where` instead of `find_by(username: '...')` and get a single instance that way?

Comment: I suppose I could have done that as well. `.first` also works, but was wondering why you can't put an array with a single object in inside .authenticate (the result to `.where`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more important question is: *Why should it*? Just because your expectations weren't met doesn't mean it's wrong.

What `where` returns is a scope, though in many cases it *behaves* like an array. Technically it isn't one, but it will do its utmost to appear to be one when necessary, such as when you call `first` on it, or ask for things like `length` or `any?`

Calling `authenticate` on a scope makes no sense, that's not a method that's supported. Calling `authenticate` on a single model instance *does* make sense, that's how you're supposed to do it.

The easiest fix here is to ask for one record if you want one record:

```
if found = AdminUser.find_by(username: params[:username])
  authorized_user = found.authenticate(params[:password])
end
```

You can also do it this way with `find_by!` which will throw an exception if no user was found matching those criteria. This allows you to chain things:

```
def login
  @authorized = AdminUser.find_by!(username: params[:username]).authenticate(params[:password])

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  # No such user
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Model.where` *happens* to produce an array with only a single element, but other times it will have more.

Since the `authenticate` method only works on a single record, it's better design to pass it a single record. Active record queries (i.e. the `where` result) and instances have totally different method sets, so you couldn't just pass a query and expect it to act like a record. Magic only goes so far.

Comment: In the above example, there was only one object within the array, hence was wondering why did it not accept the array with one object in it?

Comment: @the12 if you have a method `def foo(string)` then `foo("")` is not the same as `foo([""])`. In other words, you can't just act like the array doesn't exist because it just has one element. It's still an array, with a different set of methods.

Comment: Ok so you're saying that .where doesn't support arrays?

Comment: @the12 no. as tadman says, `where` returns an array-like object which responds to array methods but is not technically an array. Regardless of whether you think of the `where` result as a 'query' or 'array', you cannot pass it to a method which expects a _single record_ (not the same thing as an array with one element).